# Lucene Delete Document Issue

Tags: java, lucene

I am currently working with Lucene 4.2.0 and trying to delete a specific Document with a particular IntField.

Below is the structure of the Document and code for writing document in index:

```
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_42);
indexWriterConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_42, analyzer);
index = new RAMDirectory();    

Document doc;
    try {
        doc = new Document();
        doc.add(new StringField(FILENAME, "document", Field.Store.YES));
        doc.add(new IntField(EPOCH, 10, Field.Store.YES));
        doc.add(new LongField(LEADER, 10000, Field.Store.YES));
        doc.add(new IntField(COUNTER, 0, Field.Store.YES));

        logger.info(doc.toString());
        writer.addDocument(doc);
   } finally {
        writer.commit();
        writer.close();
    }
```

I am trying to delete the document based on specific value of COUNTER field:

```
Query testQ = NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange(COUNTER, 0, 0, true, true);

IndexWriter writer = null;

     try {
          writer = new IndexWriter(index, indexWriterConfig);
          writer.deleteDocuments(testQ);

      } finally {

          if (writer != null) {
              writer.commit();
              writer.close();
          }
      }
```

After executing above code, when I search for documents present in the index, I can still see the document.

I am not sure what am I doing wrong, but I want to delete documents based on a single particular value of COUNTER Field.

I am new to Lucene and also looked for issue in which the range query represents just a single value but couldn't find any post regarding the same.

(When I try searching for the Document using the same query, it returns the result correctly but when deleting it is unable to find the same Document to delete)

Comment: Are you reopening your `IndexReader` after the deletion?

Comment: yes I am doing it .  I am reopening the IndexReader.

Comment: Well, it works for me:  http://pastebin.com/PRSW7sXD